# Как "обновить" openGL в SFML?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

В SFML есть возможность использование openGL (логично), однако его версия 1.1 - слишком старая.
Есть ли возможность использования более новой версии (например 4.6 или любая 3.0+)?
И если есть, то что конкретно необходимо для этого сделать?

Comment: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-opengl.php

Comment: Та я уже читанул тупа

Comment: Просто как-то на красное внимание не обращал..